# MPAndroidChart grid inconsistent spacing

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have the following graph:

[image: MPAndroidChart]

However, I want the graph to start at exactly 0. So I tried:

```
chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(0.0f);
```

But it left me with this:

[image]

But now there are more labels, they don't land on my points and worst of all the gaps between the gridlines are not all the same, making it look a mess. Is there something more I need to do?

Here are two more examples of the same thing in another graph:

[No axis min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HblDX.png)

[Axis min zero with strange spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVU5f.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have gridlines in both axes (it's the default). You can remove the right grid axis programmatically:

```
myChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
```

If this by itself does not also solve the landing problem, you can set the number of grids and labels on the left axis programmatically like this:

```
myChart.getAxisLeft().setLabelCount(6);
```